# how to use HTML tag to show table in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I get text from API which contain html tags. How to display it I mean in UILabel? I try do with NSAttributedString, but not that I need.

Below is my response

```
<div id="Details" class="a-section a-spacing-extra-large">
<div id="feature_div" class="feature" data-feature-name="Description" data-cel-widget="feature_div">
<div id="feature_div" class="a-row feature" data-feature-name="productDescription" data-template-name="productDescription" data-cel-widget="productDescription_feature_div">
<div id="productDescription" class="a-section a-spacing-small">
<p>Manual caulking guns have a thrust ratio; the higher the thrust ratio, the easier it is to dispense the caulk, sealant, or adhesive.</p>
<div></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="p13n-m-desktop-dp-sims_session-similarities-sims-feature-4" class="celwidget" data-cel-widget="desktop-dp-sims_session-similarities-sims-feature-4">
<div class="a-section similarities-widget sims-carousel-holder" data-similarity-type="desktop-dp-sims_session-similarities"></div>
</div>)
"Hi"
Optional(<ul class="a-unordered-list a-vertical a-spacing-none">
<li><span class="a-list-item">dispesing rebaring</span></li>
<li><span class="a-list-item">Easy to handle</span></li>
<li><span class="a-list-item">frame caulking gun</span></li>
<li><span class="a-list-item">requires less force </span></li>
<li><span class="a-list-item">to help prevent dripping</span></li>
</ul>
<div>
<table id="product-specification-table" class="a-keyvalue">
<tbody>
<tr><th class="a-span4 a-text-right">Brand Name</th>
<td>ICFS359</td>
</tr>
<tr><th class="a-span4 a-text-right">Colour</th>
<td>Red</td>
</tr>
<tr><th class="a-span4 a-text-right">Included Components</th>
<td>IDispenser Caulking Gun</td>
</tr>
<tr><th class="a-span4 a-text-right">Material Type</th>
<td>Steel</td>
</tr>
<tr><th class="a-span4 a-text-right">Number of Items</th>
<td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr><th class="a-span4 a-text-right">Number</th>
<td>ICFSDM</td>
</tr>
<tr><th class="a-span4 a-text-right">Size</th>
<td>Standard</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>)
```

I tried this one

```
extension String {
    var htmlToAttributedString: NSAttributedString? {
        guard let data = data(using: .utf8) else { return NSAttributedString() }
        do {
            return try NSAttributedString(data: data, options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html, .characterEncoding:String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue], documentAttributes: nil)
        } catch {
            return NSAttributedString()
        }
    }
    var htmlToString: String {
        return htmlToAttributedString?.string ?? ""
    }
}
```

but I want show my response in below format,

Brand Name                                              ICFS359

Capacity                                                  10

Please help

Comment: Do you use cocoapods?

Comment: Do you have to use a UILabel?  Displaying it in a uitextview would be much easier

Comment: For html content use wkwebview

Comment: "but not that I need." What when wrong? What's your issue exactly ? What's the rendering? How should it render?

Comment: @Larme, it does not show table format.content show one below another.

Comment: I got this https://imgur.com/sXJuZYE and that's what you want, no? So show more code because you didn't use correctly. For instance, in your HTML code, there is `Optional(<ul`, which seems clearly be a mistake on your side. So I removed it to make it work. There are also parenthesis whithout explaination...

Comment: @valosip - it show same result on textview too.

Comment: @Larme - yes, i want the same result as you showed in image.

Comment: Don't you see the "Optional(" Why do you have it? What's your code? How did you construct your HTML String ? How I am suppose to guess what's wrong?

Comment: @Larme - I remove "Optional(" from response.i just call htmlToString from extension on textView example = txtView.text = (customParams["value"] as! String).htmlToString.

Comment: "htmlToString"? You are supposed to call `htmlToAttributedString`! `txtViewFeature.attributedText = (customParams["value"] as! String). htmlToAttributedString` That's why I was asking what's your current rendering? Do you see the HTML tags? Because I would have spotted directly the `.text` instead of `.attributedText`...

Answer (score 0):

With the above extension that you provided, you can use UILabel
Lets assume you have a string that holds the response html value like so:

```
let htmlString = "<div id="Details">".htmlToAttributedString
label.attributedText = htmlString
```

Or since I see an optional in that response, instead of force unwrapping it or force casting as a String:

```
if let htmlString = response["value"]  {
    label.attributedText = htmlString.htmlToAttributedString
}
```

This is what it will look like:
https://ibb.co/zFQLqmp
If thats what you're looking for